# How to use loop to get values out of Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to loop through each value in `startDayValStr`, `endDayValStr`, `startTimeValStr`, `endTimeValStr` and use the values as parameters in a URL string.  I am using every other value as my `end` variables, i.e. `06:00:00` is a `startTimeValStr` value and `07:00:00` is an `endTimeValStr` value.

How do I correctly construct my loop to use these variables in `time_param`?

I would like for `time_param` to look like this `?start=05-05-2019T06:00:00Z&end=05-05-2019T07:00:00Z`

Here is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd

rng = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2019-05-05' + ' ' + "'06:00:00'"),periods=25, freq='H')

 dtSeries =  pd.Series(rng.format())

 ddf = dtSeries.to_frame(name='Date')
 ddf['time'] = pd.to_datetime(ddf['Date'])
 dateDF = ddf['dates'] = ddf['time'].dt.date
 timeDF = ddf['dates'] = ddf['time'].dt.time

 startDayVal= dateDF[::2]
 endDayVal = dateDF[1::2]

 startTimeVal= timeDF[::2]
 endTimeVal = timeDF[1::2]

 startDayValStr = (startDayVal.to_string())
 endDayValStr =(endDayVal.to_string())

 startTimeValStr = (startTimeVal.to_string())
 endTimeValStr = (endTimeVal.to_string())

 for startDate, endDate, startTime, endTime in zip (startDayValStr, endDayValStr, startTimeValStr, endTimeValStr):
          time_param = '?start='+ startDate  +'T'+startTime + 'Z' + '&end='+ endDate  + endTime + 'Z'
          print time_param
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with some string manipulation you can get your result

```
startDayValStr = (startDayVal.to_string(index=False)).replace(' ','').split('\n')
endDayValStr =(endDayVal.to_string(index=False)).replace(' ','').split('\n')


startTimeValStr = (startTimeVal.to_string(index=False)).replace(' ','').split('\n')
endTimeValStr = (endTimeVal.to_string(index=False)).replace(' ','').split('\n')

for startDate, endDate, startTime, endTime in zip (startDayValStr, endDayValStr, startTimeValStr, endTimeValStr):
  time_param = '?start='+startDate+'T'+startTime+'Z'+'&end='+endDate+endTime + 'Z'
  print time_param
```

OUTPUT

```
?start=2019-05-05T06:00:00Z&end=2019-05-0507:00:00Z
?start=2019-05-05T08:00:00Z&end=2019-05-0509:00:00Z
?start=2019-05-05T10:00:00Z&end=2019-05-0511:00:00Z
?start=2019-05-05T12:00:00Z&end=2019-05-0513:00:00Z
?start=2019-05-05T14:00:00Z&end=2019-05-0515:00:00Z
?start=2019-05-05T16:00:00Z&end=2019-05-0517:00:00Z
?start=2019-05-05T18:00:00Z&end=2019-05-0519:00:00Z
?start=2019-05-05T20:00:00Z&end=2019-05-0521:00:00Z
?start=2019-05-05T22:00:00Z&end=2019-05-0523:00:00Z
?start=2019-05-06T00:00:00Z&end=2019-05-0601:00:00Z
?start=2019-05-06T02:00:00Z&end=2019-05-0603:00:00Z
?start=2019-05-06T04:00:00Z&end=2019-05-0605:00:00Z
```

Comment: Is the first number here the index? `?start=02019-05-05T006:00:00Z&end=12019-05-05107:00:00Z` The date should be 2019 for every row, please update the code and I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 1):

If using `Python 3.x`, try [`string.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting) method, with [`date.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```
rng = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2019-05-05' + ' ' + "'06:00:00'"),
                    periods=25, freq='H')

for start, end in zip(rng[::2], rng[1::2]):
    time_param = '?start={}&end={}'.format(start.strftime('%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%SZ'),
                                           end.strftime('%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%SZ'))
    print(time_param)
```

[out]

```
?start=05-05-2019T06:00:00Z&end=05-05-2019T07:00:00Z
?start=05-05-2019T08:00:00Z&end=05-05-2019T09:00:00Z
?start=05-05-2019T10:00:00Z&end=05-05-2019T11:00:00Z
?start=05-05-2019T12:00:00Z&end=05-05-2019T13:00:00Z
?start=05-05-2019T14:00:00Z&end=05-05-2019T15:00:00Z
?start=05-05-2019T16:00:00Z&end=05-05-2019T17:00:00Z
?start=05-05-2019T18:00:00Z&end=05-05-2019T19:00:00Z
?start=05-05-2019T20:00:00Z&end=05-05-2019T21:00:00Z
?start=05-05-2019T22:00:00Z&end=05-05-2019T23:00:00Z
?start=06-05-2019T00:00:00Z&end=06-05-2019T01:00:00Z
?start=06-05-2019T02:00:00Z&end=06-05-2019T03:00:00Z
?start=06-05-2019T04:00:00Z&end=06-05-2019T05:00:00Z
```